# Post link to picture with tumbnail with Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making an app that scrapes funny images from various places from the internet, and people can easily share them. When they share it, I want them to post a link to the image, not upload it. However, I want it to show up on their news feed and their friend's news feed.

I want to post a news feed, with my own title, description, I want the URL that is being posted to be something like: http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/the_image , but the thumbnail image to be that of the image itself.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to do this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the graph API to HTTP Post to the `me/feed` specifying the URL to the image (no uploading required), the title , and description, Facebook will make it's own thumbnail to show in the user's feed.